# Drupal 8 - Check if language prefix is present in url or not

Tags: i18n-l10n

Is there a way in the drupal 8 api to figure out if a language prefix is present in the url or not? Cause I need this information in order to display a custom language switcher if no prefix exists in the url. So for language detection I only have the prefix enabled.

Unfortunately this code is not working for me:

```
$languagecode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
```

Cause it always returns me a language. When no prefix is present in the url it returns me (as excepted) the fallback language.

Has someone a similar situation or can help me here?

Answer (score 2):

There might be something more elegant, but doing it the dirty way is pretty simple:

```
$languagecode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
$parts = array_filter(explode('/', \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri()));

$has_prefix = count($parts) && $parts[0] == $languagecode;
```